# flash as3: Can I get byte from spesific frames that has been loaded

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First I've try make  a preloader in my flash apps and it runs succesful but when I check the percentage text, it's not start at 0% and after the preloader reach 100& it go to 2nd frame.
Then I think it caused by the byte is counted from first not after frame 1 finish loaded.
Is there any solution about this so the counter of percentage text is start at 0%.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just give a "firstFrame" variable that will be populated once first "Progress" event will fire. Something like that:

```
private var firstFrame:int=0;
function progressHandler(e:ProgressEvent):void {
    if (firstFrame==0) firstFrame=e.bytesLoaded;
    if (e.bytesTotal<=firstFrame) displayZero(); // placeholder
    else displayPercentage((e.bytesLoaded-firstFrame)/(e.bytesTotal-firstFrame));
}
```